# Cannot start Apache Spark 1.5.1 with "failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master"

Tags: apache-spark

I downloaded pre-built Spark 1.5.1 and ran "./sbin/start-master.sh" script. And it gave me the following error.

```
rsync from spark://mycomputer:7077
ssh: Could not resolve hostname spark: Name or service not known
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /root/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/../logs/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-mycomputer.out
failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master:
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
  Could not find the main class: org.apache.spark.launcher.Main. Program will exit.
full log in /root/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/../logs/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-mycomputer.out
```

Now I solved the rsync issue by removing environment variables "SPARK_HOME" and "SPARK_HOME".

But I am still getting the following error.

```
failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master:
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
  Could not find the main class: org.apache.spark.launcher.Main. Program will exit.
full log in /root/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/../logs/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-mycomputer.out
```

Does anyone know any known issues?

Comment: What does the log file say?